# Skipping part of a ReactiveForm during validation

Tags: forms, angular

I have the following ReactiveForm in my Angular (2.4.x) app:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  // ...more pages
  page3: this.fb.group({
    classId: '',
    createClass: this.fb.group({
      id: ['', Validators.required],
      room: '',
      headTeacher: '',
    })
  })
})
```

Basically the `createClass` group is a sub-form, embedded in an expandable fieldset within the main form, just to shorten the user journey. It should be omitted during validation though. So I added the following validator to the `page3` group:

```
page3: this.fb.group({
  //...
},{validator: (c: FormGroup) => {
  return c.get('createClass').valid ? null : 'anyNotNullValue'
}}
```

...hoping that I wouldn't have to call the `.setValidators()` when collapsing/expanding the fieldset. It actually does not work - the `createClass` group is always included in validation (`console.log(c)` shows I am testing the correct FormGroup). I also tried to pass the validator straight as a row function parameter, rather than a member of an object.

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/OJgtVrkZfNlZNfPd7aWt?p=preview)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you make a plunkr?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Updated post with plunkr link

Comment: problem solved by moving the conditional section into a separate form